# How to keep track of existing data each time I add a new Item dynamically

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

```
<div ng-controller="MyCtrl">
  <button ng-click=addItem()>add Item</button>
  <div ng-repeat="item in content">
    <my-directive category-options="categoryOptions" item-options="itemOptions" category-option-change="categoryOptionChange(selectedOption)" delete-item="deleteItem(index)" index={{index}}></my-directive>
  </div>
</div>

myApp.directive('myDirective', function() {
  return {
    scope: {
      categoryOptions: "=",
      deleteItem: "&",
      index: '@',
      itemOptions: "=",
      categoryOptionChange: "&"
    },
    restrict: 'AE',
    template: "<p>\r" +
      "\n" +
      "    <select ng-model=\"categoryOptions.selectedOption\" ng-options=\"option as option.name for option in categoryOptions\" ng-change=\"categoryOptionChange({selectedOption:categoryOptions.selectedOption})\">\r" +
      "\n" +
      "         <option value=\"\">choose</option>\r" +
      "\n" +
      "    </select> \r" +
      "\n" +
      "    <select ng-model=\"itemOptions.selectedOption\" ng-options=\"option as option.name for option in itemOptions\">\r" +
      "\n" +
      "        <option value=\"\">choose</option>\r" +
      "\n" +
      "    </select>\r" +
      "\n" +
      "     [<a href ng-click=\"deleteItem({index:index})\">X</a>]\r" +
      "\n" +
      "</p>\r" +
      "\n"

  }
});
```

Each time I click, a new item is added with two select controls. Based on first select control selected option, second select control options changes.
And user can add any number of items he can.
Till here it is working fine. The problem that I am facing is lets say if I add a item and change a option in select control and then add a new item, then newly added item is also showing the same data that was selected previously.
I know this is databinding issue, but I am not sure how to efficiently solve this so that

1. Default 'choose' options should be shown whenever I add a new item.
2. I should be able to keep track of data in each item if it changes.

I have included a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/krteja/xbqga8m6/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest following solution. A working example can be found at - [@sumit Plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/8QiBiQQ3O0D2mpcBaknK?p=preview) 
Here's a code sample:

```
var app = angular.module('app', []);

app.controller("mainController", function($scope) {
  $scope.content = [];
  $scope.addSentence = function() {
    $scope.content.push({});
  };
  $scope.deleteItem = function(index) {
       $scope.content.splice(index, 1);
  };
  $scope.categoryOptions = [{
    name: "Books"
  }, {
    name: "Electronics"
  }];
  $scope.itemOptions = {
    books: [{
      name: "Harry Potter1"
    }, {
      name: "Harry Potter2"
    }, {
      name: "Harry Potter3"
    }],
    electronics: [{
      name: "Computer"
    }, {
      name: "Phone"
    }, {
      name: "Television"
    }]
  };
});

app.directive('myDirective', function() {
  return {
    scope: {
      categoryData: "=categoryOptions",
      deleteItem: "&",
      index: '@',
      itemData: "=itemOptions",
      categoryOptionChange: "&"
    },
    restrict: 'AE',
    templateUrl: "itemSelectTemplate.html",
    controller: function($scope) {
      $scope.itemOptions = [];
      $scope.categorySelectedOption = {};
      $scope.itemSelectedOption = {};
      $scope.categoryOptionChange = function(selectedOption) {
        if (selectedOption !== null) {
          switch (selectedOption.name) {
            case "Books":
              $scope.itemOptions = $scope.itemData.books;
              break;
            case "Electronics":
              $scope.itemOptions = $scope.itemData.electronics;
              break;
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
});
```

Hope this will help you! :)

Answer (score 0):

Attach a controller to the directive, and in the directive controller deal with itemOptions on a per-directive basis. You need to store state for each directive separately, but you're not - you're storing state for all directives on the parent scope.